# Sqoop command - Missing argument for option: merge-key

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

Table import using lastmodified and --merget-key option in sqoop command in cloudera. it is throwing missing argument exception while executing the command. here is my command

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --table orders_temp --incremental lastmodified --check-column order_id --split-by order_id --username root --merge-key --P
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
18/11/09 22:42:15 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.0
Missing argument for option: merge-key
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Comment: Any help team? Still i didn't get any response

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the name of a column to use as the merge key: `--merge-key <col>`.